# Importing css always yields "file not found"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to import `CSS` in a component inside the `style` sections and no matter what path I provide (which I have double checked and it is 100% correct), the app fails to build due to not being able to find that file.

Assuming I have added `a.css` to the `assets` folder under the `src` folder which results in the following path `@/assets/a.css` or `./src/assets/a.css`, when I import the file with the following code, it always fails due to not being able to find the file. The same error happens when pointing to the `static` folder as well.

```
<style scoped>
   @import '@/assets/a.css'
</style>
```

How can this be done? I need to scope `CSS` to components and reuse them.

Comment: Did you try to import using relative path?

Comment: @acdcjunior: no but can you provide an example so that I can give it a try?

Comment: @acdcjunior: `../assets/a.css` also failed

Comment: Might try '@import '@../assets/a.css' or '@import '@../../assets/a.css'  or '@import '@../../../assets/a.css'.  It depends on where it is in relation to the file.

Comment: The only thing that worked was `../../assets/a.css` but I personally don't like it because the path may be very deep resulting in something like `../../../../` sometimes. Why is the `@/assets/a.css` failing?

Comment: How about `@import 'src/assets/a.css'`?

Comment: @acdcjunior: also not working :/

Comment: Show a screenshot of the files and folders involved.

Comment: @Zaxxon: its exactly `src\assets`, my components is in folder `src\components\reusables`. The only thing that works is `../../assets/a.css` because it's two steps inside `src` but this approach makes the code dirty and hard to read.

Comment: `<style src="@/assets/a.css'"></style>`or as a relative path? But using `src` is the problem. Solved?

Comment: @Asqan: that isn't allowed in Vue